# Playback of multiple audio files on different channels

Tags: c#, .net, audio

Im researching into this for a possible future project. The customer wants to make a small solution where they need playback of multiple (different) audio files on different channels. The setup is a computer with a sound card which has 6 different output channels, and I need to develop a small application where they can determine which audio file (eg. mp3) need to be played back on which channel.

My research seem to point to external 3rd party libraries. I would like to manage all this myself.

- Any idea on how to list all available output channels on a sound card (device) ?
- How do I playback an audiofile on a specific output channel?

Any ideas on how to accomplish this are most welcome - so are alternative solutions

Cheers,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is this open source library for audio decoding and playback:

http://naudio.codeplex.com/

To manage multiple channels, windows will generally see them as different output devices, so you can use standard api for this type of playback.

I would recommend using ASIO drivers tho if possible, it will give you a much better control over channels.